# framelayout edittext not expanding as expected

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I have a problem in edit text its not getting expanded as I type.
I wanted it to show a maximum of 4 lines but when I click the exittext to type something, its shrinking, not even completely showing a single line.

the code used is.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Comments"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.28"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="11">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list2"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="true">


            </ListView>



        </FrameLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">



                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/enter_message"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                     />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/send_button"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

screen shot of whats happening..[image: edittext screenshot]
thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two framelayouts nested in a linearlayout and they are weighted. The first nested framelayout has a weight of 11 
compared to 1. So the edittext will not be able to expand beyond it's the weighted width for the framelayout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10">
```

The nested frames.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="11">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

The total parent layout has been broken in 12 parts. The top frame has 11, the bottom 1. 1 is not much. There is not enough room to display all the text, plus you have a vertical scrollbar. The text will be added and be scrolling as you type. It would be impossible to read as it scrolls in such a short space.

I would even suggest not setting the weight for the bottom frame (it defaults to 0) and then try setting the top one to say 3? and increase it to see what works for you. Please try this, before commenting again.

Comment: if I set it to match parent  the image button next to it also gets covered.

Comment: I am not able to accomplish it with weights if I increase the weight the edittext box is only growing bigger in size. is there any better alternative to this so that I can achieve something similar to other messaging apps where theres a small edittext at the bottom and a send button next to it.

Comment: I am very sorry if its confusing...yes I do want the edit text to grow as the user types but should display only four lines.

Comment: I attached a screenshot for your reference. may be now u get the picture of what my problem is.